# How to delete str(name+size+cancel) in website when file was deleted in server.javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I use ajaxsubmit to upload file to linux server .File name+file size + cancel button will appear in my website after upload file successfully.Here is my html code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.files{height:10px; font-size:10px;line-height:22px; margin:10px 0}
</style>
<div class="files"></div>
```

My ajaxsumit code is:

```
$("#myupload").ajaxSubmit({
        dataType:  'json',
       ......
success: function(data) {
files.html(files.html()+"<br />"+"<b id='dataname'>"+data.name+"("+data.size+"k)</b> <span class='delimg' rel='"+data.pic+"' id='cancelbtn'>cancel</span>");
 },
 ......
```

When cancel button is clicked,File name+file size + cancel button will disappear .Here is my js code:

```
$(document).on('click',".delimg",function(){
    var filename = $('#dataname').val()+"cancel";
            files.html(files.html().replace(new RegExp(filename,"g"),""));
});
```

Unfortunately,it worked fail.Here is example which i want to realize.Before click cancel, my files div content is :

```
1.jpg(10.36k) cancel
2.jpg(10.36k) cancel
3.jpg(10.36k) cancel
```

After i click the second cancle,my files div content is:

```
1.jpg(10.36k) cancel
3.jpg(10.36k) cancel
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `id='dataname`.

You can't use multiples times the same `id`.
Use a class instead.
[More reading about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page) here.

So...
`<b class='dataname'>`
instead of
`<b id='dataname'>`

and remove the useless `id='cancelbtn'`.

Then your click event handler should be:

```
$(document).on('click',".delimg",function(){
    $(this).prev('.dataname').remove(); // removes the filename
    $(this).remove(); // Removes the "cancel"
});
```

There is no need for a regular expression here.
You have classes to target the elements to remove.

Regex are used to target character patterns in a string.

Comment: ,How to use a class? Can you show me the code?  Sorry ,I hava no idea about using class.

Comment: I improved the answer with some concrete stuff. ;)